# Plug-in method call in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I've created two plug-ins.

**Extension point (Plugin 1):**

```
edu.xyz.harsha.tetris
```

**Extension (Plugin 2):**

```
edu.xyz.harsha.tetrisext
```

plugin1 has `Tetris` class which calls `Clock` class. I defined `Clock` class in plugin2. Now I want to use `Clock` class in plugin1. How can I use methods of `Clock` class from plugin2 in `Tetris` class of plugin1?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: add Required Plugin in **Dependency** in your manifest file.

Comment: Generally, it is not a good idea to have a circular dependency. In your scenario, plugin1 depends on plugin2 for the Clock class, and plugin2 depends on plugin1 for the extension point. You might want to redesign, maybe moving something from one plugin to another or to a third plugin.

Answer (score 1):

In the MANIFEST.MF editor for plugin2 add the package which contains your `Clock` class to the 'Exported Packages' section of the 'Runtime' tab. This will add a 'Export-Package' entry to the MANIFEST.MF.

In the MANIFEST.MF editor for plugin1 add plugin2 to the 'Required Plug-ins' section of the 'Dependencies' tab. This will add a 'Require-Bundle' entry to the MANIFEST.MF

You should now be able to import 'Clock' in the normal way in your Java code.